# Arduino Uno - MQTT message using PUBSUB on ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, mqtt

I'm trying to write code involving MQTT messages to operate an ESP8266 relay ( a Sonoff device ), using `PubSub` library.

For some, unknown for me, reason - messages larger than 99 chars are not sent. It this a known limitation ? can it be changed ?

```
void pub_msg(char *inmsg){
        char tmpmsg[255];
        // sprintf(tmpmsg,"[Cl:oc:k] [%s] %s",deviceTopic, inmsg);   ---> wish to add a time stamp
        sprintf(tmpmsg,"[][%s] %s",deviceTopic, inmsg);  ---> using this line just to find that 99 chars sent OK
        Serial.print("published MSG:");
        Serial.println(tmpmsg);
        Serial.print("Total chars:");
        Serial.println(strlen(tmpmsg));
        client.publish(msgTopic, tmpmsg);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum MQTT packet size in PubSubClient is 128 bytes. After all the MQTT header information that leaves only 99 bytes for a message.

You can change it by editing the `PubSubClient.h` file:

```
#ifndef MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE
#define MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE 128
#endif
```

As it says in the PubSubClient [README.md](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/blob/master/README.md):

> - The maximum message size, including header, is **128 bytes** by default. This is configurable via `MQTT_MAX_PACKET_SIZE` in `PubSubClient.h`.

Comment: Can you please refer to its location ?

Comment: The location of the file, or the location within the file?

Comment: sorry- location of the file

Comment: It's wherever you installed it to.

Comment: Is it part of `pubsub` library ?

Comment: If it's the same library I know of, yes.

Comment: what is valid value ?

Comment: Anything that will fit into available memory really. Work out how big you will need.